# Calling a function from a module

Tags: linux, fortran

I'm trying to do something real simple, just call a function that is defined in a module but its not working and I can't figure out why.

this is what I do to compile it using linux

```
gfortran -o testingMOD testMod.f90 doubleMod.f90
```

this is the error

```
 testMod.f90:3.4:

use doubleMod
    1
testMod.f90:8.15:

 call double(n)
               2
Error: 'double' at (1) has a type, which is not consistent with the CALL at (2)
```

here is the code
the module:

```
module doubleMod
 implicit none

 contains
 function double (n)
  implicit none
  integer :: n, double

    double = 2*n
    write(*,*) double
 end function double

end module doubleMod
```

the file calling it:

```
program testMod

use doubleMod

 implicit none
 integer :: n = 3

 call double(n)

end program testMod
```

Comment: `call` is for subroutines, not functions.

Comment: Try replacing `call double(n)` with `write(*,*) double(n)` and see what happens.

Comment: The recursive I/O may be problematic, though, @HighPerformanceMark.  So, perhaps `n=double(n)`.

Comment: Ah yes, there is that.  Let's see what OP reports !

Comment: Why do you write the correct answers in a comment? OP can't accept a comment as correct.

Comment: thanks @francescalus this was the problem!

Answer (score 2):

Fortran has two main types of procedures: Functions and Subroutines. Functions return a value, so they are called inside an expression. Examples:

```
a = myfunc(b)
print*, myfunc(a)
```

Subroutines do not return a value, they need to be called:

```
call mysub(a, b)
```

Trying to `call` a function or use a subroutine in an expression is a syntax error.

In your case, you could **either** convert `double` into a subroutine:

```
subroutine double(n)
    implicit none
    integer, intent(inout) :: n
    n = 2 * n
end subroutine double
```

Then your `call` to `double` would result in the value of `n` to double.

**OR** you can change how you invoke `double`:

```
program testMod
    use doubleMod
    implicit none
    integer :: n
    n = 3
    n = double(n)
    print*, n      ! prints 6
end program testMod
```